# I can't go to a directory with C++

Tags: c++, directory

I need to change working directory of my project, so that output files go to a certain folder, not where all the project files are.

I'm using

```
system("cd secretdir/");
system("ls");
```

However, what I get, is the list of files in current project directory, not the "secretdir" one.

I'm on Mac OS X 10.6/Qt Creator 4.7 64 bit

Thanks!

Comment: For reference, using `system` should be a last resort.  Aside from spawning a new shell every time it's called, it's also quite prone to being tricked into running stuff you never intended it to.  If you must spawn another program, try one of the `exec` family of instructions.

Comment: You mention QT Creator so the easiest way would be QDir::setCurrent("secretdir");

Comment: He might be using QtCreator just as an IDE and not actually using the Qt library.

Comment: cHao, thanks for the advice. I solved the problem by using chdir(), however, there's one more thing. I'm writing a checking system, it launches executables and compares their output files.  I got there. I use system() to run the executables. However, I need to make sure that they don't run for more than 5 seconds, because otherwise they can run for ever and the checker will never get to the next test. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your current code will spawn a subshell that will change its current directory to `./secretdir`, then proceed to `exit()` without doing anything else.

Only then will `ls` run in *another* subshell, whose current directory is, of course, completely independent of what you did during your previous call to `system()`.

That's probably where your problem lies. Are you looking for the [chdir()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/chdir) function?

```
chdir("secretdir");
// From now on, the current directory of the process is `./secretdir`.
system("ls");  // Will probably behave as expected.
```

Comment: This doesn't do *anything* for the requirement "so that output files go to a certain folder".

Comment: @Ben, you're right, I misread the question. Answer updated, thanks for the heads-up :)

Answer (score 8):

You have to change the current working directory

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/how-to-change-current-working-directory-in-c-550031/

Also, you should consider saving your output files with full path names instead of changing the working directory.

Comment: Definitely a pointer in the right direction, however Mac OS-X is based on BSD, not linux.  For this particular question it doesn't matter of course, since `chdir` is POSIX.

Comment: How is this just a "pointer in the right direction"? Just because it's on linuxquestions? It's a posix library.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, too bad I can't select two accepted solutions.

Answer (score 2):

**edit** See Falmarri's response as I glossed over the first sentence of your question.

You can also use [`chdir`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/chdir.html)

**the following is crufty**

The first `system` spawns a new process that does the `cd`. The second `system` spawns a completely different process that doesn't know what happened previously.

One thing you could do is:

`system("ls secretdir/");`

Comment: This doesn't do *anything* for the requirement "so that output files go to a certain folder".

Comment: +1 for the idea of using the full interface of the shell commands instead of trying to work around them - but AFAICT, the OP is only doing 'ls' for testing purposes, and the real goal is to change the program's working directory.

Answer (score 2):

I'd highly recommend checking out `QDir`, `QFile`, and `QProcess` objects in the QT Creator help or online documentation since you are using it.  They have very detailed and easy to understand documentation and using the tools available to you in QT should be a primary reason for choosing that tool much of QT rivals boost in portability and usability in my limited experience.

Also there is a great community for QT related questions at [QTForum](http://www.qtforum.org/index.html) worth bookmarking especially if QT Creator is your primary development environment.

Using `system` should be avoided as general rule of thumb it is inefficient and insecure in many cases.

EDIT: Sorry I too glossed over your first sentence and jumped to the code bits.  You can modify the project settings via the Projects tab in QT Creator to add a Custom Process step to the build where you can specify a working directory and then do a copy command to wherever you would like your output to go.  You also may be able to specify a build output option within your .pro file directly ... once again the help and documentation is your friend however.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The function on Mac OSX is [`chdir("./secretdir")`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/chdir.2.html), although since it's a POSIX API it actually works the same on many other platforms as well.

Answer (score 1):

Using system() is not portable so try to avoid to use directly "cd" like that. My advice is to use [Boost filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm).

There is a [Two-minutes Tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm#tutorial) !

Answer (score 0):

Do

```
system("cd secretdir/; ls");
```

Or better yet use boost's [filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm) library. Maybe just [opendir](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/opendir.3.html).

Comment: You may wanna reverse those commands.  cd'ing after you `ls` makes even less sense than trying to cd then ls in two separate processes.

Comment: @AJG85: YES! Boost aside from destroying compilation times and producing rather cryptic errors that make STL look like a walk in the park, makes life so much simpler.

Comment: @cHao: duly noted, didn't have my morning coffee yet.

Comment: This doesn't do *anything* for the requirement "so that output files go to a certain folder".  OTOH your suggestion of `boost` is good, there's a `current_path("./secretdir");` function that would change the active process's working directory.

Comment: QT which he is using already also has this via QDir::setCurrent(QString somePath);